# Upload file to Nextion-Display from ESP32

Tags: esp32, nextion

Is there a way to upload directly files from ESP32 to Nextion Display?
I want to download pictures or TFT file with ESP 32 WIFI and upload it to Display. It would be really great if I can do it with a TFT file!

Comment: I know this comment is a year old but it is now possible. For downloading new TFT files and sending them up to your Nextion, you can use this library: https://github.com/Nredor/ESPNexUpload

For moving pictures, you can use the new SD commands found on the Nextion Intelligent series screens: https://nextion.tech/intelligent-series-introduction/

Search 'twfile' on this instruction page to see the commands needed: https://nextion.tech/instruction-set/

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for a solution to this also for a car computer with sat nav.
But as far as I can tell it cant be done unless somebody hacks the nextion firmware.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure I've seen an example for this once, but I can't seem to find it at the moment. The Nextion Editor updates the display over serial, so it should technically be possible. You could capture the serial data when doing an upload from Nextion Editor to see how it is done. I'll come back and edit my answer if I find the sample code or attempt this myself.